# Error handlers in neo4j-php-client

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

I downloaded and installed neo4j-php-client and neo4j 2.3.2. Actually all works fine, but I just wondering why there is no error handlers in this php client? For example if there is an error in cypher query, no error has throwing to be easy to catch it. I searching through the network, but I can't found a solution.

Do anybody have an idea how to turn on error handlers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the maintainer of `neo4j-php-client`.

When you send a query to Neo4j, it is actually sent via Guzzle.

Of course there is a try/catch block for handling exceptions, which is located here :

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/blob/master/src/HttpClient/GuzzleHttpClient.php#L76

If there is an error in your cypher query, an exception will be thrown of course, the exception is of type `Neo4jException` (https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/blob/master/src/Exception/Neo4jException.php)

Here is a simple code with a cypher syntax error and you can see an exception is thrown :

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Neoxygen\NeoClient\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('default', 'http', 'localhost', 7474)
    ->setAutoFormatResponse(true)
    ->build();

$query = 'MATCH (n) RETURN x';

$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($query)->getResult();
```

-

```
ikwattro@graphaware ~/d/g/p/neo4j-php-client> php test.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\Neo4jException: Neo4j Exception with code "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax" and message "Variable `x` not defined (line 1, column 18 (offset: 17))
"MATCH (n) RETURN x"
                  ^" in /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php(104): Neoxygen\NeoClient\Extension\AbstractExtension->checkResponseErrors(Array)
#1 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/NeoClientCoreExtension.php(98): Neoxygen\NeoClient\Extension\AbstractExtension->handleHttpResponse(Object(Neoxygen\NeoClient\Request\Response))
#2 [internal function]: Neoxygen\NeoClient\Extension\NeoClientCoreExtension->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) RETUR...')
#3 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/ExtensionManager.php(53): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-cli in /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php on line 117

Fatal error: Uncaught Neoxygen\NeoClient\Exception\Neo4jException: Neo4j Exception with code "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax" and message "Variable `x` not defined (line 1, column 18 (offset: 17))
"MATCH (n) RETURN x"
                  ^" in /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php:117
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php(104): Neoxygen\NeoClient\Extension\AbstractExtension->checkResponseErrors(Array)
#1 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/NeoClientCoreExtension.php(98): Neoxygen\NeoClient\Extension\AbstractExtension->handleHttpResponse(Object(Neoxygen\NeoClient\Request\Response))
#2 [internal function]: Neoxygen\NeoClient\Extension\NeoClientCoreExtension->sendCypherQuery('MATCH (n) RETUR...')
#3 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/ExtensionManager.php(53): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-cli in /Users/ikwattro/dev/graphaware/php/neo4j-php-client/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php on line 117
```

Comment: I cannot catch Neo4jException using try/catch blocks. Is it normal?

Comment: I opened a new question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720179/graphaware-neo4j-php-client-cannot-catch-neo4jexception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. The problem is seems on my end, I figured out after few tests - Error hanldering overwrites by the php framework.